# Which chapter of the manga does Season 4 of My Hero Academia anime start in?

Tags: my-hero-academia

The trailer of Season 4 of the anime *My Hero Academia* has been released, and I'm assuming that by knowing in which chapter of the manga Season 3 of the anime ends, you can know which chapter of the manga Season 4 starts.

Which chapter of the manga does Season 4 of *My Hero Academia* anime start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mangaupdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=112459) and the [wikia](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/My_Hero_Academia_Season_3), *Boku no Hero Academia* adapted up to **Chapter 124** in Season 3. Therefore, Season 4 is expected to adapt the chapters after that, starting in **Chapter 125**.